# strange behavior of scanf for short int

Tags: c, scanf, undefined-behavior

the code is as follows:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
main()
{
    int m=123;
    int n = 1234;
    short int a;
    a=~0;
    if((a>>5)!=a){
        printf("Logical Shift\n");
        m=0;
    }
    else{
        printf("Arithmetic Shift\n");
        m=1;
    }
    scanf("%d",&a);
    printf("%d\n", m);
}
```

after the line `scanf("%d",&a);` the value of m becomes **0**.

I know it may be caused by the scanf: a's type is short and the input's type is int. But How can this affect the value of m ?

Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The most likely reason for `m` being `0` in your snippet is because you assign `m` to have this value in the body of your if-statement, but since the code contains *undefined behavior* no one can say that for sure.

---

### The likely story about passing a `short*` when scanf expects an `int*`

Assuming `sizeof(short) = 2` and `sizeof(int) == 4`.

When entering your main function the stack on which the variables reside would normally look something like the below:

```
  _
 |short int (a)   : scanf will try to read an int (4 bytes).
 |_ 2 bytes       : This part of memory will most
 |int       (n)   : likely be overwritten
 |                :..
 |
 |_ 4 bytes
 |int       (m)
 |
 |
 |_ 4 bytes
```

When you read a `%d` (ie. an `int`) into the variable `a` that shouldn't affect variable `m`, though `n` will most likely have parts of it overwritten.

---

### Undefined Behavior

Though it's all a guessing game since you are invoking what we normally refer to as "*undefined behavior*" when using your scanf statement.

Everything the standard doesn't guarantee is UB, and the result could be anything. Maybe you will write data to another segment that is part of a different variable, or maybe you might make the universe implode.

Nobody can guarantee that we will live to see another day when UB is present.

---

### How to read a `short int` using `scanf`

Use `%hd`, and be sure to pass it a `short*`.. we've had enough of UB for one night!

Comment: @IntermediateHacker You should +1 my little black ass for doing this: **[click here for incognito pron, we don't have cookies](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/10/loungec)** (it's a link to the SO chat room `Lounge<C++>`)

Comment: *Most answers in this thread are not far from being completely wrong!* is misleading and Incorrect, Almost every answer says it is **Undefined Behavior** and Once you say that any possible explanation of the after effect is at best a *likely guess*.So I am unable to understand what your Opening statement means.

Comment: @Als it was a bit sarcastic, I'm tired and.. I'm tired, I can change the title for you if you'd like.

Comment: While you are free to say anything in your answer,The old title didn't do justice to other answers, which say the same thing as your answer does if not with same clarity.And I deleted my answer because your answer is better :)

Answer (score 2):

You are correct, `%d` expects and writes an `int`. If you enter a value less than `65535`, it fits in the bytes outside `short`, so you see `0` when you print `a` back. I tried reading a `short` and printing it back; I entered `65536123`, and got `123`, which makes perfect sense (65536 occupies precisely 16 bits; you see the remaining `123` through the two bytes of the `short`). This behavior is dangerous, because the other two bytes of the `short` end up in a "variable next door" to the `short`, which is very, very bad. I hope this should convince you not to do it.

P.S. To read a `short` with `scanf`, declare a temporary `int` variable, read the value into it using `scanf`, and then cast it to `short`.

Comment: Technically, passing anything **except** `int *` to scanf when it expects int is UB. Won't someone _please_ think of the nasal demons?

Comment: @moshbear that's true - my compiler warned me twice that "warning: format ‘%d’ expects type ‘int *’, but argument 2 has type ‘short int *’" Ignoring your compiler warnings is a recipe for trouble.

Comment: An alternative to storing in a temporary `int` is to use, e.g., `scanf("%hd", &a);` for the `short int a`.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that `int` and `short` are four- and two-byte integers, respectively, on your platform (which is a likely assumption, but not guaranteed by the standard), you're asking `scanf` to read in an integer and store it in four bytes: the two bytes of `b`, and whatever two bytes follow it in memory. (Well, technically this is undefined behavior, and no specific behavior is guaranteed; but that's what it's likely to do.) Apparently your compiler is using the two bytes after `b` as the first two bytes of `m`. Which is a bit surprising — I certainly wouldn't expect `b` and `m` to be adjacent, and it rather implies that your compiler isn't aligning `short`s and `int`s to the beginning of four-byte blocks — but perfectly legal.

You can see better what's going on if you add

```
printf("&a: %08X\n&m: %08X\n", (int)&a, (int)&m);
```

which will show you where `a` and `m` are stored, relative to each other. (Just as a test, I mean. You wouldn't want that in "real" code.)

Answer (score 1):

You're invoking Undefined Behavior when passing a pointer to a non-int to scanf's %d.

Likely, the compiler introduces padding bytes for alignment purposes and the values get stored in the padding bytes and not the "useful" bytes.

However, the compiler is free to do anything from raise a segfault / access violation to invoke nasal demons.

Answer (score 1):

If you had actually used variable `n`, then it would probably have been the one that got clobbered, rather than `m`.  Since you didn't use `n`, the compiler optimized it away, and that means that it was `m` that got clobbered by `scanf()` writing 4 bytes (because it was told that it got a pointer to a (4-byte) integer) instead of the 2 bytes.  This depends on quite a lot of details of your hardware, such as endian-ness and alignment (if `int` had to be aligned on a 4-byte boundary, you wouldn't see the problem; I guess you are on an Intel machine rather than, say, PowerPC or SPARC).

Don't fib to your compiler - even accidentally.  It will get its own back.